# ExpressJS webseite works local but returns 403 Forbidden online

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to get [this example](https://github.com/yTakkar/Vue-Mini-Social-Network) [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) app running on my server.
Offline (on localhost) it is working correctly after running `npm start`.

I uploaded all files, installed everything through *npm install*, started the *nodemon* through SSH `npm start`and got the `App Running` response.

If I try now to open the URL of the website it returns **403 Forbidden**.

What do I need to change to make it work?

(It's my first time working with ExpressJS - maybe it's just a noob issue. Could this be a HOST or PORT issue?)

Comment: probably a port issue, explain your hosting setup abit